# How do I check the elapsed non-responsive time of a task?

Tags: windows-7, tasks

I want to check the elapsed time an active task has been non-responsive in Windows. Is there a function or program in windows that can display this to me?

Comment: There may be an entry created in Windows Event Viewer, how much detail I cannot tell you.....https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-solve-your-windows-problems-with-event-id/